# Indexing tables of logical vectors with zero counts in R

Tags: r

I have the following:

```
> v1 <- c(T, F, T, T, F)
> table(v)
v
FALSE  TRUE 
    2     3
```

To index the 'True' column, I do this:

```
> `table(v1)[2]`
TRUE 
   3
```

However, if a logical vector contains only `FALSE` values, the table will only have one column and the previos strategy no longer works to retrieve the `TRUE` column:

```
> v2 <- c(F, F, F, F, F)
> table(v2)[2]
<NA> 
  NA
```

How can one consistently index the `TRUE` column regardless of if its count is zero? One solution is to do this:

```
> table(factor(v2, levels= c("FALSE", "TRUE")))[2]
TRUE 
   0
```

But this feels like cheating because it treats `TRUE` and `FALSE` as characters that become levels of a factor. For non-logical vectors, this behaviour is understandable, because there is no way of knowing what levels exist. (1) Is there a way to force `table()` to take into consideration the fact that logical vectors only take on two values and always present two columns for them? (2) Am I overthinking this and the last command is an acceptable and robust practice?

Comment: In light of the fact that TRUE and FALSE in the output of `table` are names and so are character already using character does not seem to be inconsistent.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck Would this behaviour remain consistent if the call is `table(factor(v2, levels= c(FALSE, TRUE)))[2]`, i.e. using reserved words instead of characters?

Comment: Factor labels are always character.  If `f` is the factor created in your comment look at `dput(f)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Convert to `factor` with `levels` specified so that it always have two `levels` - without a `TRUE` value, there is no way the `table` to create the count of TRUE as that information is not present.  With `factor` `levels`, it gives the `TRUE` count to be 0

```
table(factor(v2, levels = c(FALSE, TRUE)))[2]
```

---

It is not clear why a logical vector TRUE values needs to be counted with `table` and then extract based on the `TRUE`, `FALSE` names.  It can be more easily done with `sum` as `TRUE` -> 1 and `FALSE` -> 0, negating (`!`) reverses this

```
> sum(v1)
[1] 3
> sum(!v1)
[1] 2
> sum(v2)
[1] 0
> sum(!v2)
[1] 5
```

Comment: While I didn't know the levels could be `TRUE` and `FALSE` themselves -instead of strings- and appreciate the insight (caveat: `[2]` returns the `FALSE` column instead of  the `TRUE` column because it respects the order passed to `levels`), I already proposed your solution and was looking for an alternate way. Maybe I'm in fact overthinking and this is a valid solution.

Comment: @Zweifler sorry, didn't see your last code block while I answered. Instead of doing table and then extracting, wouldn't this be more direct with `sum`

Comment: @Zweifler Also, just a note of caution - I wouldn't recommend creating an object with `T`, `F` as this can break the code depending on the packages loaded or objects created e.g. `F` is a function in `collapse`, instead use the reserved words `TRUE/FALSE`

Comment: I have accepted your answer, but please correct the example using `table` (invert the order of the factors) not to mislead anyone.

Answer (score 1):

Because the case of `logical` is so specific for the requirements, I would write a specific function:

```
logitable <- function(x)
{
    x <- as.logical(x)

    kNA  <- sum(is.na(x))
    kT   <- sum(x, na.rm=TRUE)
    kF   <- length(x) - kT - kNA

    return (structure(
       c(kT, kF, kNA),
       names = c("TRUE", "FALSE", "NA")
    ))
}
```

Please note that the type of the return object is not of class `"table"` --- let me know if this is important to you, to return such an object.

Test with:

```
logitable(c(T,F,T,F,T))
logitable(c(T,T,T,T,T))
logitable(c(F,F,F,F,F))
logitable(c(T,F,T,F,NA))
```